# How are p-values in fittings estimated?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I am trying to understand how p-values retrieved in a *ParameterTable* estimated but I couldn't find any specific information in the documentation about this. For instance, considering

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}};
lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x];
lm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image]

How is the p-value of `x` computed? [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81203/1370) explains why the p-value should be accepted/rejected and what it means. But my question is related with how it is actually computed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this particular example the P-values can be found with the following:

```
2 (1 - CDF[StudentTDistribution[2], 0.268373])
2 (1 - CDF[StudentTDistribution[2], 2.95892])
```

The "2" in `StudentTDistribution[2]` is the degrees of freedom calculated from the sample size (4) minus the number of parameters estimated (2).

In this case the P-value is the probability of observing a more extreme t-Statistic given that the associated parameter is actually 0.  This is the probability that the observed t-Statistics under repeated sampling when the true parameter is zero could be larger than 0.26873 or less than -0.26873 (i.e., a two-tailed test).